# Mapped texture to a gluSphere not wrapping correctly

Tags: java, rendering, jogl

I have a 3D sphere rendered using **JOGL** by means of `GLUquadric`. I'm trying to add a texture but it is not rendering as correctly.

Does anyone understand why the texture (upper-right of sphere) isnt being wrapped, nor repeated around the rest of the sphere?

[image: Textured Sphere]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really bad UV coordinates.

If two vertices use the SAME uv coordinate, the final color will be the same between both vertices, because they sample the same texel in the texture.

I suggest you check out the [gluQuadricTexture](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~haoz/teaching/htmlman/quadrictexture.html) function.